# How to load Jpanel in a Jframe using button click (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, panel, jbutton

I'm using netbeans IDE and I created a Jframe with two Jpanels one is for Jbuttons and other one is for load another Jpanels to it when clicks those buttons.
I tried to do it from buttonclick action.

`Jpanel2 j2=new Jpanel2();
JPanel1.add(j2);
j2.setVisible(True);`

but this code is not working. I want to know how can I do this.
(I think this is also same as loading JinternelFrames)

Comment: you need to remove the previous panel before adding another on it or set its visibility to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call revalidate() method.

Comment: How to do it ?  I mean how can I use revalidate() method ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a card layout and do it correctly.You can learn how to use card layout [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)